# How can I use the OSM SRTM plugin for Osmosis program?

Tags: openstreetmap, srtm, osmosis, josm

I am using `Osmosis` and I have a test `.osm` map. I want to install a plugin from the following Github repo:

https://github.com/locked-fg/osmosis-srtm-plugin/

I have followed the steps to "install" it by creating a '`plugins`' folder and placing the binaries of the plugin in the floder as mentioned in there. Unfortunately, it shows the following error on running this command:

```
osmosis.bat --read-xml myMap.osm --write-srtm --write-xml mySrtmMap.osm
```

This gives the following command-line errors:

[Errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aPjl.png)

Can anybody please explain if I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the `plugins` folder is created inside the `bin` folder of osmosis.
Next, download the jar file from https://dl.bintray.com/locked-fg/Osmosis-Srtm-Plugin/ and put it in the plugins folder.